# Android: The onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) returning Id as 0 everytime?

Tags: android

i'am doing a small app in android.And in gridviewitemclicklistner it returns id=0 everytime please help me?

```
g2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {  
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
             int position, long id) 
         {  
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,''+id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `position`-variable instead. The fact that `id` returns 0 simply means that the clicked row doesn't have an id. (Which it probably doesn't in your case. So I don't think there is a real problem here.)

Answer (score 0):

In your list adapter, you must have overriden `getItemId()` to return 0 each time. Here, you must return a unique ID for each list item.